# Induced map between Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, representable-functors

Definition : Let $S$ be a scheme, $\mathcal E$ a quasi coherent $\mathscr O_S$-module, and $e \geq 0$ an integer. For every $S$- scheme $h : T\longrightarrow S$ denote by $$ \operatorname{Grass}^e(\mathcal E)(T) = \{ \mathcal U \subseteq h^{*}(\mathcal E) \;|\; \textrm{$h^*(\mathcal E)/ \mathcal U$ is a locally free $\mathscr O_T$-module of rank $e$}  \}$$

Now it is mentioned in the book that for every surjection $v :\;\mathcal E_{1} \longrightarrow \mathcal E_2$ induces a morphism $$i_v : \operatorname{Grass}^e(\mathcal E_2) \longrightarrow  \operatorname{Grass}^e(\mathcal E_1)$$

My difficulty is I am not able to define the later induced morphism explicitly.

My attempt : Since $h^*$ is a right exact functor given surjection $v :\;\mathcal E_{1} \longrightarrow \mathcal E_2$ I have surjection $v :\;h^*\mathcal E_{1} \longrightarrow h^*\mathcal E_2$.
Now by definition I have to produce a map from $$i_v(T) : \operatorname{Grass}^e(\mathcal E_2)(T) \longrightarrow  \operatorname{Grass}^e(\mathcal E_1)(T)\\\mathcal V \longrightarrow \mathcal U$$ 
Now I know that for every $\mathcal V \subseteq h^*(\mathcal E_2)$ I have a preimage $\mathcal U \subseteq h^*(\mathcal E_1)$ but then I am stuck in defining the desired induced morphism.

Any hint or help is appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Which book do you read?

Comment: I don't really see your issue, but if in doubt go look at EGA I, Grundlehren edition, 9.7.8

Comment: Minor comment: the fact that $h^* \mathcal{E}_1 \to h^* \mathcal{E}_2$ is surjective requires that $h^*$ is right exact, not just that $h^*$ is a functor.

Comment: @ Andras Batkai the name of the book is Ulrich Gortz, Torsten Wedhorn, Algebraic geometry Schemes with examples and exercise

Comment: @ Mere actually I will have to prove that $i_v$ is a closed immersion, so that's why I am trying to find and explicit image (a quasi coherent ideal sheaf in some sense) so that I have a closed subscheme.

Comment: @cgodfrey yes you are right I will edit it to make it more precise.

Comment: @Mere thank you very much for your comment will look into the reference and get back to you.

Comment: @Zen that's all proven in the reference I mentioned. It's certainly the best reference on this topic.